# Calculated Property using a Parameter with RIA Services

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I am performing distance calculations between addresses.  Specifically the distance between a User and a particular location.  I can build the LINQ queries that cause the database to calculate the distance and order the results by that distance.  However, I can't find a way to **RETURN** that distance in the Entities.  A simplified version of the query is below:

```
    public IQueryable<Place> GetPlacesWithinRadiusOfUser(double userLongitude, double userLatitude, int miles )
    {

        return (from Place in this.ObjectContext.Places
                where RadiusOfEarth * Math.Acos((double)
                    (Math.Sin((double)Place.Addresses.First().Latitude / DegreesToRadians) * Math.Sin(userLatitude / DegreesToRadians))
                    +
                    (Math.Cos((double)Place.Addresses.First().Latitude / DegreesToRadians) * Math.Cos(userLatitude / DegreesToRadians)
                    * Math.Cos((userLongitude / DegreesToRadians) - ((double)Place.Addresses.First().Longitude / DegreesToRadians))
                    )
                    )
                    <= miles
                select Place);


    }
```

Essentially, the math from above I need to return as a **Distance** property on the **Address Entity** (which is child of Place).  I have created the following partial class and the field does appear in the silverlight client.

```
public partial class Address
{
    //The Distance field is used to return a distance if a reference point is provided in a query
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Distance { get; set; }

}
```

So, the **Distance** property and calculation is dependent on the parameters of the **GetPlacesWithinRadiusOfUser** method.

Is there a way to get the parameters from the query to the **Address Entity** so that I can perform the same calculation and have it available in the Entity upon arriving at the client?

I can certainly create a client side routine that will do this calculation but this will get messy as I will have to continually inject that in every UI that needs it.  I would much prefer to return it in the Entity so that I can just bind to it and display it (essentially I want a calculated field returned from SQL).  If it were striaght SQL, this would be trivial but I am at a loss as to how to do this with RIA Services and the Entity Framework.

And thoughts?

Comment: One thought: create DTO's with calculation results and use those in your data transfer. Just curious: you can't use sql server spatial types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Entity Framework, I was never able to find a way to actually do this (the way I wanted to).  However, I found a pretty good solution.  Steps are as follows:

1. Created the query by issuing the distance calculation on the ObjectContext....then filtered a Place query by the returned values.  All of that is done in one query call from the client.  It doesn't return the distance...but I handled that a different way.
2. I then created extension methods on all of the relavent objects like so:

   ```
   public static class AddressExtensions
   {


   public static double CalculateDistanceTo(this Address address1, double longitude, double latitude)
   {
       if (address1 == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }

       return Global.CalculateDistance((double?)address1.Longitude, (double?)address1.Latitude, longitude, latitude);

   }

   public static double CalculateDistanceTo(this Address address1, Address address)
   {
       if (address1 == null || address == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }

       return Global.CalculateDistance((double?)address1.Longitude, (double?)address1.Latitude, (double?)address.Longitude, (double?)address.Latitude);

   }

   public static double CalculateDistanceTo(this Address address1, User user)
   {
       if (address1 == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }

       return address1.CalculateDistanceTo(user.Addresses.FirstOrDefault());

   }

   public static double CalculateDistanceTo(this Address address1, Place place)
   {
       if (address1 == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }

       return address1.CalculateDistanceTo(place.Addresses.FirstOrDefault());

   }
   }
   ```
3. Then, anywhere I needed to get the distance, I could do something like User.DistanceTo(myAddress)

This actually worked out a little better because I could then reuse the same extension methods no matter what the situation.